# Handling BackKeyButton in nested PreferenceScreens in Android

Tags: android, preferencescreen

I have a PreferenceScreens like this

```
<PreferenceScreen android:id="outer">
 <PreferenceScreen android:id="outer">
  <ListPreference ...></ListPreference>
    <PreferenceScreen android:id="inner1">
      <CheckboxPreference ...></CheckboxPreference>
      <CheckboxPreference ...></CheckboxPreference>
      <CheckboxPreference ...></CheckboxPreference>
 </PreferenceScreen>  
  <PreferenceScren  android:id="inner2">
  </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScren>
```

1) So when I am clicking the preferencescreen with id "inner1", one new preference screen       is coming with all my checkboxpreferences. After doing some operations in that preferencescreen, I am pressing backbutton to goto my main PreferenceScreen (id outer).
I want to perform some operation when user presses the backkey in preferencescreen(id inner1), how to handle it?

I cant use public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) because it is not getting triggered (bcoz it is not an activity).

Could anyone help me  ............?

Answer (score 0):

For preference we do have preference activity you can extends it in your activity and then you can get access to onkeydown or onkeyup methods also. I hope this link will help you. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am extending from preferenceactivity only and handling onkeydown but onkeydown method is getting called for outer preference screen(android:id outer) not in the inner preferencescreen(android id:inner1).